# Unable to use NVIDIA GPU on Ubuntu 18.04 for computer vision task (GeForce GTX 1060)

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu-driver, tensorflow

My machine is a ASUS ROG SCAR-GL703GM-EE033T with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX1060. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it and the necessary softwares needed to run deep learning applications using its GPU.

I installed:

- Cuda 10.0
- cuDNN 7.5.0
- tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1

and everything looks fine, as when running the following command in a Python terminal:

```
tensorflow.test.is_gpu_available()
```

it outputs the characteristics of the NVIDIA card and "True". So the installation looks correct.

However, when running an application for computer vision that uses pytesseract, I'm surprised by the long run-time that may indicate the GPU isn't really used. To verify that, when the code is running I display in another terminal the `nvidia-smi` command that outputs:
[this screenshot of nvidia-smi command when code is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9cGI.png)

As you can see the NVIDIA driver is 418.67. It is not the one recommended by NVIDIA website ([here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) with GeForce / GeForce 10 Series / GeForce GTX1060 / Linux 64-bit), but I tried unsuccessfully to install driver 430.67 with following message:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Thu Jul 11 17:56:00 2019
installer version: 430.34

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 12 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 12.
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-uvm' appears to already be loaded in your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X server, a CUDA program, or the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading, and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to reboot your computer.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I then tried with driver 418 that ended up with tensorflow recognizing available GPU, so I continued with it.

Also, as you can see in screenshot no process uses GPU. And as you can see in the screenshot that Cuda version displayed is 10.1 althought before installing 10.0 that looked working best I erased all traces of previously installed 10.1. Why would `nvidia-smi` get this 10.1 version of Cuda?

Do you know, with my current configuration/installation, how to permanently make GPU available for my code running? Do you see a missing point in my installation?

Thanks for your help, I tried to provide as much details as I could!

Théo